# CountVectorizer token_pattern to not catch underscore

Tags: python, regex, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

CountVectorizer default token pattern defines underscore as a letter

```
corpus = ['The rain in spain_stays' ]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r'(?u)\b\w\w+\b')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

gives:

```
['in', 'rain', 'spain_stays', 'the']
```

this makes sense since AFAIK '/w' is eqivilent to [a-zA-z0-9_], what I need is:

```
['in', 'rain', 'spain', 'stays', 'the']
```

so I tried replacing the '/w' with [a-zA-Z0-9]

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r'(?u)\b[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]+\b')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

but I get

```
['in', 'rain', 'the']
```

How can I get what I need?
any ideas are welcome

Comment: `\w` also matches `_` so there is no word boundary between these two chars `n_`

Comment: so what can I use instead of '/w' to get the desired result?

Comment: Without the word boundaries, you could use for example `[^\W_]+` https://regex101.com/r/zN3Oax/1

Comment: Or using boundaries in the form of lookarounds `(?:(?<=[\s_])|(?<=^))[^\W_]+(?=[\s_]|$)`  https://regex101.com/r/QaREpI/1

Comment: Thnaks, works. is there any difference between the two?

Comment: Yes there is, see the matches in [this example](https://regex101.com/r/hRxRpT/1) and the matches in [this example](https://regex101.com/r/cMt58W/1) Also note that the pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]+` matches at least 2 chars. Is that intended?

Comment: yes it is it intended, totally forgot about that, thanks

Comment: A shorter way to write the previous could also be `(?<![^\s_])[^\W_]+(?![^\s_])` https://regex101.com/r/zzZgzU/1

Comment: the more general '\W' is actually better for me, using [^\W_][^\W_]+ for the 2 char issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no word boundary between `n_` as `\w` also matches an underscore.

To match 2 or more word characters without an underscore, and allowing only a whitespace boundary or an underscore to the left and right:

```
(?<![^\s_])[^\W_]{2,}(?![^\s_])
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<![^\s_])` Negative lookbehind, assert a whitspace boundary or an underscore to the left
- `[^\W_]{2,}` Match 2 or more times a word char excluding the underscore
- `(?![^\s_])` Negative lookahead, assert a whitespace boundary or an underscore to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dUplng/1).

---

A very broad match could be `[^\W_]{2,}` but note that this does not take boundaries into account. It only matches word characters without the underscore.

See the different amount of matches in this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jYbn9U/1).